# Sync 2 svn repositories

Tags: svn, repository, synchronize

I have this scenario: I have an svn repository that is used by some people. Then, there is another group of people, that wants to work at the same application, but not on my svn repository. So, the solution here would be to have two repositories. But I also have to synchronize them. When somebody commits something in one repository, to be automatically submitted in the other one. I know that there is some master/slave structure for svn repositories, but in this case I want to be able to write in both of them, to make commits in both of them. Is there a way to do that with svn?

Thanks for replies,

Vasi.

Comment: This task is more suitable for distributed version control systems like git and mercurial, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but in this case I cannot change svn to git...

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the following: http://developer.mindtouch.com/User:PeteE/Synchronizing_SVN_Repositories_With_Svk

Comment: by the way, i also need to use it and have just successfully compiled SVK on my RHEL5. I had to compile it from source code so far as our company policy doesn't allow us to install anything under root account, we even don't have root access. So if you need something similar i might help you.

Should you need a help, please don't hesitate to ask me.